# UICollectionView as subclass of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I'm newbie with iOS

I have `UIScrollView` with several `UIView` inside.

My question: Is it possible to add `UICollectionView` as subView of `UIScrollView` but i want `UICollectionView` to be completely in separate class?

I've tried something like this

```
MyCollectionView *myCollectionView = [[MyCollectionView alloc] init];
[self.scrollView addSubview:myCollectionView];
```

but i'm getting error from xcode:

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'ProductImagesView *' to parameter of type 'UIView *'

Also i want to make it 100% programmatically (no IB).

Can somebody show me direction on code example?
Thanks.

Comment: For your information UICollectionView is already a subclass of UIScrollView. There is no need to add it again to UIScrollView. Following is the hierarchy : UICollectionView->UIScrollView->UIView->UIResponder->NSObject

Comment: Here's [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968511/preventing-wrapping-of-items-in-uicollectionview) for your answer.Go through and follow what he did.